# Simulate running a program in Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Let's say i have a program Foo, is it possible to run Foo in a sort of sandbox that returns a list of every file modified/created/removed?

---

For example i'd like to say:

```
sandboxprogram apt install htop >> log.txt
```

or

```
sandboxprogram Foo >> log.txt
```

or

```
sandboxprogram untrusted_binary >> log.txt
```

and get a list of everything changed in log.txt **keeping the system untouched**

Comment: Look about LXC!

Comment: Strictly speaking, the act of creating that log.txt would be touching the system. :)

Comment: @Tanktalus i could save the log in a different system lol

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent it from touching the system it's on. However, you can give it an ephemeral system to touch. This is what containers, such as Docker, are for. Get it running in a container that gives it the environment you want it to have (there are docker containers already containing Debian, for example), and run it under strace or similar inside that container. You can then grep through that output to find what files it opens. Then you shut down the container, and all changes magically disappear.